# Add comment count near the link Django

Tags: django, post, count, comments, blogs

I have a working blog.
Each post has a link "Comments" that leads to comments for that particular post.
I want to add comment count so it would look like: "Comments (5)" ect.

I added `% get_comment_count for post.pk as comment_count %}` value to my template, so it looks like this :

```
    {% for post in posts.object_list %}
<div class="post">
    <div class="title">{{ post.title }}</div>
    <ul>
        <div class="time">{{ post.created }}</div>
        <div class="body tresc">{{ post.body }}</div>
        {% get_comment_count for post.pk as comment_count %}
        <div class="commentlink"><a href="post/{{ post.pk }}/">{{ comment_count }} Comments</a></div>

    </ul>
 </div>
{% endfor %}
```

but I get the error :

```
Invalid block tag: 'get_comment_count', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'
```

at line containing `{% get_comment_count for post.pk as comment_count %}`.
What am I doing wrong?

My models.py looks like that :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ["title"]

class Comment(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    body = models.TextField()
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode("%s: %s" % (self.post, self.body[:60]))

class CommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    display_fields = ["post", "author", "created"]

admin.site.register(Comment, CommentAdmin)
admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

How can I use db_table to change the table Django is reading comments from?
I need it to read from `news_comment` table.

Comment: You're trying to use a list comprehension in django templates, and list comprehensions don't work in templates.

Comment: This has nothing to do with list comprehensions, it seems like the tag is not importable (or conflicts with for loop), can you try calling `get_comment_count` outside the for loop ? Also make sure you have `{% load comments %}` at the top of your template.

Comment: Ok it worked, but I get : "'int' object has no attribute '_meta'". Am I looping for something wrong or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure you load the comments template tags at the top of your template:

```
{% load comments %}
```

The `get_comment_count` expects model instance as a parameter after `for` keyword. You are passing it an integer primary key value. So you need to update it like this:

```
{% get_comment_count for post as comment_count %}
```

Comment: I got "no such table: django_comments" error. I do have a table comment in "news" app so when I open SQLite Manager in Firefox Plugin I see : "news_comment" table with many fields, such as id, body, post_id, ect.

How to link it with this table?

Comment: Make sure you have `'django.contrib.comments'` in `INSTALLED_APPS` and then run `manage.py syncdb`.

Comment: I forgot to do syncdb :)
One more thing - how can I tell Django to use different table? I have all my posts added to one named "news_comment" so the new one is empty. Can I do it somehow?

Comment: You can use `db_table` option on your model `Meta` options class. See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.db_table) on that. If you want to customize the comments model see this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/comments/custom/).

Comment: Please, look at my initial post. I added my models.py
Where should I put this code in order for Django to read from "news_comment" table instead of "django_comments" ?

Comment: You would have to use the second link i posted in last comment on customization. Django contrib comments is a generic solution, that means it is not tied to any model directly, but uses generic foreign keys to add relations. I am sorry but this is too far away from your original question.

Comment: Ok I created the app and run everything. There just seem to be the problem with column name. I have post_id columt to store the comments for each post with id. I het the error:
DatabaseError at /news/ : no such column: news_comment.comment_ptr_id

Comment: You need to delete the original `news_comment` table and let django create new one (syncdb) with the new comment model as it is missing the generic foreign key fields i was talking about. Make sure you have your custom comments app in INSTALLED_APPS to be able for syncdb to find the model.

Comment: It created the table, but something's still wrong. Anyway, thanks for tyour help!